# populating custom listview from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have this piece of code in onCreate():

```
try{
    Log.i("onCreate","Trying to open database...");
    orgi = this.openOrCreateDatabase("orgi", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Log.i("onCreate","database opened.");
    cursor = orgi.rawQuery("SELECT name from profile;",null);
    Log.i("onCreate","successfully done with query..");
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.profilelistrow,cursor, 
            new String[]{"name"},new int[] {R.id.profileListRowTV1});
    Log.i("onCreate","Adapter done");

    ll.setAdapter(adapter);

}catch (SQLException e){
    displayError(e.toString());
}
```

I'm supposed to populate the customlistview with data from the SQLite database. But then it gives me a force close right at this line:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.profilelistrow,cursor, 
            new String[]{"name"},new int[] {R.id.profileListRowTV1});
```

Can somebody tell me what is wrong? I'm pretty ignorant with the simple cursor adapter (due to my noobness in android)... R.layout.profilelistrow is my layout for the entire screen, while profileListRowTV1 is the textview where the "name" will be inserted. Please educate me on this... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what the problem because you gave us code and no error, In eclipse -> Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS. Look at the log cat when you get a force close. Any how. Here is an example my friend.

Main list XML... you can add a list view anywhere in a layout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFD0"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">



 <ListView  
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:cacheColorHint="#666666"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     />

 <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#4B89E0" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="The list is empty! Do I need this? No idea!"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

Next the row:
Now these can get pretty complicated. I have a program with a list that has 5 images and 3 text views and android seems to handle it pretty well. But here is a basic one, 3 text views...can work with one just as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- row.xml -->
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:textColor="#4B89E0" 
     android:layout_width="130dip"
     android:layout_height="40dip"
     android:textSize = "15dip"
     />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:textColor="#4B89E0" 
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:gravity = "center"
     android:textStyle = "bold"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:textColor="#4B89E0" 
    android:gravity = "center"
     android:layout_width="80dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>          

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally some code to put it together... In this example a call  fillData(); to fill the list. I usually like to do this so that when i change the database are what information I'm retrieving (ie. I want to see: all shapes or round shapes or square shapes) the list is easily updated. I'm assuming your database is already open. You opened it in OnCreate().
 Instead of having all this code in your OnCreate method  create your own method "fillData" and all you have to have in your OnCreate is **fillData();**. This will make it easier to view, edit, and troubleshoot.

```
private void fillData() {

        Cursor fetchInfo = mDbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        startManagingCursor(fetchInfo);


        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (TITLE,DATE,NUMBER)
        String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, 
                 DbAdapter.KEY_DATE, DbAdapter.KEY_AUTHOR   };

        // an array of the views that we want to bind those fields to (in this case text1,text2,text3)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row, fetchInfo, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }
```

**WakaWaka**

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be in this line.

```
cursor = orgi.rawQuery("SELECT name from profile;",null);
```

SimpleCursorAdapter as well as many of Android functions rely on having an identifier key called '_id'. So make sure your query returns your rows with that identifier. In your case, you should change that line to this

```
cursor = orgi.rawQuery("SELECT yourTableId AS '_id', name FROM profile;",null);
```

And that should solve your problem.